# Can not add background image

Tags: html, url, background-image

I am trying to provide the background image to a div. Image is in my directory

```
<div style="background-image: url('H9Vi61CWym0.jpg');"></div>
```

but i see

```
 <div style="background: url();">
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you tried to put the `background-image` on CSS file because using inline CSS is much harder to maintain. You should try this:

1 - create a `class` for your div I'll call it `myDiv` like this:

`<div class="myDiv"> your content </div>`

2 - Then put something like this on CSS file:

```css
.myDiv{
  background-image: url('H9Vi61CWym0.jpg');
}
```

Or if you want you can put it on `<style>` element inside the `<head>` element like this:

```html
<style>
.myDiv{
  background-image: url('H9Vi61CWym0.jpg');
}
</style>
```